# How would I create bins of date ranges in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi how's it going? I'm a Python developer trying to learn Spark Scala. My task is to create date range bins, and count the frequency of occurrences in each bin (histogram).

My input dataframe looks something like this

[image]

My bin edges are this (in Python):

```
bins = ["01-01-1990 - 12-31-1999","01-01-2000 - 12-31-2009"]
```

and the output dataframe I'm looking for is (counts of how many values in original dataframe per bin):

[image]

Is there anyone who can guide me on how to do this is spark scala? I'm a bit lost. Thank you.

Comment: Why  `01-01-2000 - 12-31-2009` Shows 2? ( Is not it 4 +3 = 7 ? (count (01-20-2001 ) + count(02-01-2005) ) ?
Also what's that 0 in the result ?
[edit] : Nevermind, I understood, you are counting 'entries' inside a bin range.

Answer (score 0):

Are You Looking for A result Like Following:

```
+------------------------+------------------------+
|01-01-1990 -- 12-31-1999|01-01-2000 -- 12-31-2009|
+------------------------+------------------------+
|                       3|                    null|
|                    null|                       2|
+------------------------+------------------------+
```

It can be achieved with little bit of **spark Sql** and **pivot** function as shown below

check out the **left join condition**

```
val binRangeData = Seq(("01-01-1990","12-31-1999"),
                    ("01-01-2000","12-31-2009"))
val binRangeDf = binRangeData.toDF("start_date","end_date")
// binRangeDf.show

val inputDf = Seq((0,"10-12-1992"),
                    (1,"11-11-1994"),
                    (2,"07-15-1999"),
                    (3,"01-20-2001"),
                    (4,"02-01-2005")).toDF("id","input_date")
                    
// inputDf.show

binRangeDf.createOrReplaceTempView("bin_range")
inputDf.createOrReplaceTempView("input_table")

val countSql = """
SELECT concat(date_format(c.st_dt,'MM-dd-yyyy'),' -- ',date_format(c.end_dt,'MM-dd-yyyy')) as header, c.bin_count
FROM (
(SELECT
b.st_dt, b.end_dt, count(1) as bin_count
FROM
(select to_date(input_date,'MM-dd-yyyy') as date_input , * from input_table) a
left join
(select to_date(start_date,'MM-dd-yyyy') as st_dt, to_date(end_date,'MM-dd-yyyy') as end_dt from bin_range ) b
on
a.date_input >= b.st_dt and a.date_input < b.end_dt
group by 1,2) ) c"""

val countDf = spark.sql(countSql)

countDf.groupBy("bin_count").pivot("header").sum("bin_count").drop("bin_count").show
```

Although, since you have **2** bin ranges there will be **2 rows** generated.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by looking at the `date` column and determining within which range each record falls.

```
// First we set up the problem

// Create a format that looks like yours
val dateFormat = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy")

// Get the current local date
val now = java.time.LocalDate.now

// Create a range of 1-10000 and map each to minusDays 
// so we can have range of dates going 10000 days back
val dates = (1 to 10000).map(now.minusDays(_).format(dateFormat))

// Create a DataFrame we can work with.
val df = dates.toDF("date")
```

So far so good. We have date entries to work with, and they are like your format (`MM-dd-yyyy`).
Next up, we need a function which returns 1 if the date falls within range, and 0 if not. We create a `UserDefinedFunction` (UDF) from this function so we can apply it to all rows simultaneously across Spark executors.

```
// We will process each range one at a time, so we'll take it as a string 
// and split it accordingly. Then we perform our tests. Using Dates is
// necessary to cater to your format.
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def isWithinRange(date: String, binRange: String): Int = {
  val format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy")
  val startDate = format.parse(binRange.split(" - ").head)
  val endDate = format.parse(binRange.split(" - ").last)
  val testDate = format.parse(date)

  if (!(testDate.before(startDate) || testDate.after(endDate))) 1
  else 0
}

// We create a udf which uses an anonymous function taking two args and 
// simply pass the values to our prepared function
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

def isWithinRangeUdf: UserDefinedFunction =
  udf((date: String, binRange: String) => isWithinRange(date, binRange))
```

Now that we have our `UDF` setup, we create new columns in our `DataFrame` and group by the given bins and sum the values over (hence why we made our functions evaluate to an `Int`)

```
// We define our bins List
val bins = List("01-01-1990 - 12-31-1999",
                "01-01-2000 - 12-31-2009",
                "01-01-2010 - 12-31-2020")


// We fold through the bins list, creating a column from each bin at a time,
// enriching the DataFrame with more columns as we go
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit}

val withBinsDf = bins.foldLeft(df){(changingDf, bin) =>
  changingDf.withColumn(bin, isWithinRangeUdf(col("date"), lit(bin))) 
}

withBinsDf.show(1)
//+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
//|      date|01-01-1990 - 12-31-1999|01-01-2000 - 12-31-2009|01-01-2010 - 12-31-2020|
//+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
//|09-01-2020|                      0|                      0|                      1|
//+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
//only showing top 1 row
```

Finally we `select` our bin columns and `groupBy` them and `sum`.

```
val binsDf = withBinsDf.select(bins.head, bins.tail:_*)
val sums = bins.map(b => sum(b).as(b)) // keep col name as is
val summedBinsDf = binsDf.groupBy().agg(sums.head, sums.tail:_*)

summedBinsDf.show
//+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
//|01-01-1990 - 12-31-1999|01-01-2000 - 12-31-2009|01-01-2010 - 12-31-2020|
//+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
//|                   2450|                   3653|                   3897|
//+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

2450 + 3653 + 3897 = 10000, so it seems our work was correct.
Perhaps I overdid it and there is a simpler solution, please let me know if you know a better way (especially to handle `MM-dd-yyyy` dates).